# Multiple statements in for-loops

Tags: scala

In java you can do something like this:

```
 Boolean foo = true;
 for(int i=0; i<10 && foo; i++) {
     doSomething();
 }
```

Is it also possible in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible but not the best practice. Do you want to continue with next record if foo == false or break? Does doSomething modify foo? Take a look at fold and forall in scala api

```
 for (i <- 1 to 10 if foo) { doSomething() }
```

Comment: I did some testing an this is the perfect solution.

Comment: This is not the same as Java for loop. In the Java for loop above there is a int counter. Here it actually create a list (well range..) iterate over it. So it pretty much like `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).foreach{ if foo doSomething() }`

Comment: @roterl You are absolutely right. Usually I do something like (1 to 10).forall({doSideEffects; returnBoolean})

Comment: This is very inefficient way to do it.

Comment: sorry I didnt feel like writing tailrecursive or stream based implementation for a loop that goes from 1 to 10

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the 2 options:

1. use your `foo` variable to filter undesired results

```
var foo = true
for (i <- 0 to 9 if foo) {
    doSomething()
    if (<want to break?>) foo = false
}
```

2. use `break`:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

breakable {
    for (i <- 0 to 9) {
        doSomething()
        if (<want to break?>) break
    }
}
```

... though I generally suggest to shape your algorithms in more FP-ish/Scala way and avoid having mutable state or cycles (and breaks in them) when possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
val foo: Boolean = true
for{
  i <- 0 until 10
  if foo
} doSomething()
```

Comment: Thanks, would `for(i <- 0 until 10; if (foo))` also be an option?

Comment: @Busti yes, without the `;`